# What causes some mathematical journals to discontinue?

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, journals

This is soft question. I decided to ask my question on MathOverflow rather than on academia StackExchange because I believe that the community here is more equipped to answer the question.

The [Graduate Journal of Mathematics](https://gradmath.org/) mentions in its mission-statement that it takes inspiration from a similar journal that was discontinued in 2000: Le Journal des Elèves de l’Ecole Normale Supérieure de Lyon. I have searched about the later journal "Le Journal des Elèves de l’Ecole Normale Supérieure de Lyon" in google but found no active webpage for it.

- Can someone tell me about the journal "Le Journal des Elèves de l’Ecole Normale Supérieure de Lyon" ?
- Why it was discontinued ?

There are there other journals which were also discontinued for publication. For example, [LMS Journal of Computation and Mathematics](https://www.lms.ac.uk/publications/jcm) was discontinued in 2015.

> So what causes some mathematical journals to discontinue?

My main motivation for the above questions is the following:

> Suppose someone publish an article in a journal and later the journal get closed. How would people evaluate the work from a journal which is closed ?

Comment: You can find the published issues of *Le journal des élèves de l'ÉNS Lyon* here: https://jmeenslyon.wordpress.com/

Comment: @PseudoNeo, thank you for the webpage. Does it still publish papers because I saw 2021 edition ?

Comment: The page https://jmeenslyon.wordpress.com/histoire_jme/ says that the journal stopped operating in 1998 and was restarted in 2015.

Comment: @ANG: I don't think it does.

Comment: I can think of WW3. The second question might then become irrelevant, see Tom Lehrer's song "We shall all go together when we go".

Comment: @RolandBacher, WW3 ? World War 3 ? ohh, is there WW3 among journals ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At https://futurelms.wordpress.com/2016/01/14/save-the-lms-journal-of-computation-and-mathematics/ you will find discussion of the decision to close the LMS Journal of Computation and Mathematics.  My knowledge is based solely on a brief scan of the documents linked from that page. It seems that some people felt that the papers in the journal were not of high quality and were seldom read.  The decision to close was narrowly confirmed by a vote at a special general meeting of the LMS.

Comment: Thank you. So if someone publish in a journal and later the journal gets closed. what will happen ? Should the author worry about it ? Because in some case, some publishes papers in journals which he/she includes in his/her Ph.D. thesis. So if a journal gets closed, would the Ph.D. degree be still valid in that case ?

Comment: As I said, I have no special knowledge of this situation; you can read the linked documents as well as I can.